# 1602 LCD through I2C with an FT232h not working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, lcd

I have a Raspberry Pi trying to drive a 1602 Character LCD that's connected through the I2C pin outs on an FT232H breakout board (from adafruit). However, I am unable print anything to it. I can see the address of the LCD through running this python script

```
import board
import busio
import time

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

while not i2c.try_lock():
    pass

while True:
    print("I2C addresses found:", [hex(device_address)
    for device_address in i2c.scan()])
    time.sleep(2)
```

And see that it reports a `I2C addresses found: ['0x20']`.

When I run `i2cdetect -y 1` though, I do not see any devices connected.

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I figured this was just because the LCD screen was being driven from the ft232h so I didn't have much concerns. However I am still unable to write anything to it and when I run the following script it just flashes.

```
import board
import busio
from adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_i2c import Character_LCD_I2C

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = Character_LCD_I2C(i2c, 16, 2)

while True:
    lcd.message = "test"
    lcd.backlight = True
```

Comment: Any pointers to the LCD specification you are using? Because I have a few **brand new** I²C LCDs that are not properly working (I have some ideas to try, but do not have time).

Comment: The LCD's I have in particular are the DFRobot DFR0063 LCD DIsplay. It looks like they have a PCF8574 I2C expander in them and I think that might be the issue with the Character_LCD_I2C Library since it looks like those are made for the MCP230xx chips. I'm kind of lost on how to get around it besides soldering the LCD pins directly to the Pi, but I hear that's not an ideal situation.